# jQuery - get a value from dynamically created input

Tags: jquery, input

I need your help with get a value from created input. I have to get value from input search which is generated by jquery. I have following code but it didn't work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#raport").click(function() {
        var search = $("#search").val();
        alert (search);
        })    
});
```

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: What is generated dynamically? The `raport` or the `search`? Or both?

Comment: Search is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this for the elements which will come dynamically

```
$(document).on("click" ,"#raport",function() {
```

Comment: Sorry for being vague, but search is generated dynamically. #Raport button is "normal" Html

Comment: I think then there is no problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the event in a different way as to work for newly added controls:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("click", "#raport" ,function() {
      var search = $("#search").val();
      alert (search);
   });
});
```

That way the initial listener is added to the `document` and when an element of id `#raport` is clicked, even if it is a new control, the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's the `#raport` element that is generated dynamically, you have to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#raport', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

for example if you added a new recipe in your restaurant application page through AJAX, then just use that food and price in this way.

```
$('#main_food_div').on('change','input:checkbox', function(){
      //Do your jQuery here
        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
         //alert($(this).val());
});
```